# installing nSight Studio with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to start programming CUDA.
I've installed Visual Studio 2010 Express.
I've also isntalled nVidia nSight Visual Studio.
And I have all common prerequisites (Net FrameWork, Java, ...)

But I cannot see any CUDA option in my Visual Studio options nor project properties.
What should I do?
Do I also need to install the Cuda toolkit?  It's offered as a separate package but nSight has already installed something called cuda toolkit.

regards

I'm using Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 3):

Due to a technical limitation in the Visual Studio Express editions, Nsight for Visual Studio only supports Visual Studio 2008 Professional and above and Visual Studio 2010 Professional and above.

Comment: I first tried with Visual Studio 2012 Pro but it didn't work either,  I don't know why. But Now finally I got it with VS 2010 Pro.

Comment: Nsight VSE 3.0 and earlier do not support Visual Studio 2012. Visual Studio 2012 will be supported in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Cuda toolkit and Nsight for debugging.
As far as vs 2012 is concerned did you follow this guide?
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CUDA-50-and-Visual-Studio-20e71aa1#content

Although I made it work for build I cannot debug with nsight cause its just incompatible with visual studio 2012. I've tried nsight 3 rc2 Till now, I haven't found any way to make it work and I think I have to reinstall VS 2010...

"Nsight Visual Studio 2012 support will come with the next version that is scheduled for Q2'13.
One big reason for not supporting VS2012 is that the CUDA 5.0 toolkit doesn't support the new toolchain. Sorry for the inconvenience.
I should mention that the next release candidate of Nsight 3.0 will support C++ AMP debugging in VS2012 (but no other Graphics or CUDA features will be supported)"

Comment: I'm also looking forward to using the new Q2'13 Nsight version.

Comment: @skan from my experience its always better to not use the latest versions if you are not an experienced user. You may have trouble due to lack of internet information about problems that you might face. :)

Comment: Do you mean it's going to be very different from the previous version?

Comment: @skan No i mean that new releases may hide bugs, incompatibilities etc that someone cant imagine until he face one. For example intellisense doesnt work for cuda files and vs 2012 at the moment. At least i didnt find any good post for making it work. In order to check that you have installed cuda toolkit correctly check these steps: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html In addition, take a look here http://www.stevenmarkford.com/installing-nvidia-cuda-with-visual-studio-2010/